# Timezone Region Not Found (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Does anyone know why the first query would be causing this error to be thrown while the second one works?

ORA-01882: timezone region not found 01882. 00000 -  "timezone region %s not found"

1. **Causes Error:** SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE (SELECT **t.TIME_ZONE** FROM SOME_TABLE t WHERE t.TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver' AND ROWNUM = 1) 
   FROM DUAL
2. **Works Correctly:** SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE (SELECT **'America/Denver'** FROM SOME_TABLE t WHERE ROWNUM = 1) 
   FROM DUAL

Note: This is running on a Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit db. I've verified both queries work **correctly** on another db with the same db version. Not sure what else could be causing this.

Comment: Weird. What's the data type of `SOME_TABLE.TIME_ZONE`? Is it just a varchar2?

Comment: Ah, I think that's the issue. The db with the error has a data type of NVARCHAR2 ( vs VARCHAR2 in the working db )

Comment: Yup, casting to VARCHAR2 fixed it. Thanks for the pointer!    SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE (SELECT CAST(t.TIME_ZONE AS VARCHAR2(80)) FROM SOME_TABLE t WHERE t.TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver' AND ROWNUM = 1) FROM DUAL

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the root cause, it was related to t.TIME_ZONE's data type (which was NVARCHAR2). Here's an example showing that NVARCHAR2 time zone names are not supported in 11g:

**Does not work:** SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE CAST( 'America/Denver' as **NVARCHAR2**(80)) FROM DUAL

**Works:** SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE CAST( 'America/Denver' as **VARCHAR2**(80)) FROM DUAL

Wrapping t.TIME_ZONE in TO_CHAR() fixed the problem.